# Has anyone performed the error analysis for Trapezoidal Rule but with non-uniform grid?

Tags: integration, summation, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, quadrature

I've taken courses in Numerical Analysis, but all the proofs we've examined for the error of the Trapezoidal method hinge on a uniform grid. However, I'm working on a quadrature method which depends on the difference of the function values, not the input values. Specifically, it looks something like this:
$$I(f,a,b) \approx bf(b) - af(a) - \frac12 \sum_{i = 1}^{N}[x_{i-1} + x_i]\Delta f(x_i)$$

Now, I don't need the proof for this exact statement derived, though I'm not opposed to hints. But if anyone can point out a good resource for the error analysis of the Trapezoidal rule with a non-uniform grid, which looks like this:
$$I(f,a,b) \approx \frac12 \sum_{i = 1}^{N}[f(x_{i-1}) + f(x_i)]\Delta x_i$$

or a derivation of it, then that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: If you know the error over uniform partitions, then the error over non-uniform partitions would just be a summation over those errors.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt could you link a resource for that? Or give an example?